# Python 3.2 remove newline from HTML code with urllib

Tags: python, html, string, format, urllib

I used urllib to get HTML to a string, I want to perform serach on the string but can't due to HTML format, so is there a way to 'unformatting' a string, don't need to take out HTML code, I just need to remove all the new lines.
Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request

url = "http://www.internetworldstats.com/emarketing.htm"
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
Whole=(response.read().decode('ISO-8859-1'))

Whole.strip('/n')
print(Whole[11631:12631])
YearPos=Whole.find('December, 1996')
print(YearPos)
```

The strip bit did not work.... The result I got is like this

```
    December, 1995</b></font></p>
</td>
<td width="112" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial" color=
"#000099">16 millions</font></div>
</td>
<td width="120" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial" color=
"#000099">0.4 %</font></div>
</td>
<td width="120" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<p><font size="-1" face="Arial" color="#000099">IDC</font></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="103" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<p><font size="-1" face="Arial" color="#000099">December,
1996</font></p>
</td>
<td width="112" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial" color=
"#000099">36 millions</font></div>
</td>
<td width="120" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial" color=
"#000099">0.9 %</font></div>
</td>
<td width="120" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<p><font size="-1" face="Arial" color="#000099">IDC</font></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="103" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<p><font size="-1" face="Arial" color="#000099">December,
1997</font></p
-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here...

1. As Vasili mentioned, the newline character should be `\n`, not `/n`
2. [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html) does not modify the string directly. It returns a copy of the modified string. So it should be `Whole = Whole.strip('\n')`
3. [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html) remove **leading** and **trailing** characters. In your case, you wanted to remove the newline characters which are in the middle of the string. So you should use `str.replace()` instead, e.g. `Whole = Whole.replace('\n', '')`

Answer (score 0):

You have written the newline character incorrectly, it is `\n`, not `/n`.